# Sequence contains more than one matching element - EF Database Initialize

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am working on a system that generates a database on initialization:

```
public static void initialiseEntityFramework()
{
    using (DbContextentityframework context = new DbContextentityframework())
    {
        context.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
}
```

but when it gets to the initialization is returns the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains more than one
>   matching element'

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.ForeignKeyPrimitiveOperations.<>c__DisplayClass4a.<RemoveAllForeignKeyConstraintsForColumn>b__47(ForeignKeyBuilder fk)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.EntityMappingConfiguration.CleanupUnmappedArtifacts(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType table)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Mapping.EntityMappingConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, EntityType entityType, EntityTypeMapping& entityTypeMapping, Boolean isMappingAnyInheritedProperty, Int32 configurationIndex, Int32 configurationCount, IDictionary`2 commonAnnotations)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigureTablesAndConditions(EntityTypeMapping entityTypeMapping, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.MarkDatabaseInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Initialize(Boolean force)
```

When the above `context.Database.Initialize(True);` code runs, during initialization my debugger takes to to a method that runs through 400+ instances of applying classes to a DBModelBuilder. It seems nearly all of these are fine, however there are a few instances that cause the error I am seeing. Here is an example of such an instance:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Genesis_Core_Meta.@Workers.Sources.@Worker>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Worker", "Workers");
        })
            .Property(p => p.ContactId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(
                System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity
            );
```

Where **Worker** class inherits from an **Individual** class which inherits from a **Contact** class. Each of these classes are pretty big with lots of properties and methods.

I was wondering if someone might be able to tell from the above what I might need to look for in these classes to spot what could be causing the problem?

Still a bit tenuous I know but I'm hopeful someone can help!

Comment: A stack trace would help.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing...!

Comment: I have added the stack trace... and can see that it is trying to add (what seems to be) a duplicate foreign key relationship - but I just dont know what and where?!

Comment: Try to create a [mcve]... boil it down to a small sample that still produces the problem: As it says on the MCVE page, either you'll find it yourself on the way, or others can help at that point.

Comment: Thanks Richardissimo...! I have gone through various phases of commenting out some code to see what happens but I could probably have been a little more structured in my approach to that.

Comment: Try hooking up a profiler to the database server and let it loose. Be sure to point to a local database server or something that is guaranteed to otherwise not be under use to avoid "noise" from other operations/applications. When it fails you can use the last executed queries to identify exactly which tables were being accessed.

Comment: What is the inheritance hierarchy of @Client?

Comment: Hi DevilSuichiro, Client inherits from Contact - which contains ContactId.

Comment: I have managed to deduce the issue down to adding just two classes. I think I may re-write the question a little more specifically to this one example.

Comment: Question partly re-written...  I hope this makes things at least a little more clear?!